# Accordion (Shopify) how to default to all closed

Tags: jquery, accordion, shopify

I've got an accordion working in shopify, but at the moment the first 'heading' is open when you load the page. Am looking to have all closed by default and for the life of me i can't get it to work so nay help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Anyways, here's the code at the moment:

```
   $('.accordion.headings').each(function() {
  return $(this).add($(this).next('.accordion.content')).wrapAll("<div class='accordion-wrapper'/>");
});
$('.accordion.headings li').wrapInner('<div class="trigger"></div>');
$('.accordion.headings li .trigger').append('<div class="bg"></div>');
$('.accordion-wrapper').each(function() {
  var accordion_content, accordion_heading;
  accordion_heading = $(this).find('.accordion.headings > li');
  accordion_content = $(this).find('.accordion.content > li');
  accordion_heading.first().addClass('active');
  accordion_content.each(function(index) {
    var content;
    content = $('<div class="content">' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
    return content.appendTo(accordion_heading.eq(index));
  });
  accordion_content.remove();
  $(this).find('.content').first().show();
  return $(this).find('.trigger').on("click", function() {
    var panels, this_panel;
    panels = $(this).closest(".accordion").find('.content');
    this_panel = $(this).closest("li").find(".content");
    panels.not(this_panel).slideUp(200);
    this_panel.slideDown(200, function() {
      if (general_scroll_to_active_item) {
        return $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: this_panel.offset().top - 100
        });
      }
    });
    $(this).closest(".accordion").find("li").removeClass("active");
    return $(this).closest("li").addClass("false");
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance,
s.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a shopify site that had this same feature built-in. If you remove the first line here you'll find that the accordion is closed on page load.

```
$(".faqs-container .faq-singular:first-child").addClass("active").children(".faq-answer").slideDown(); //Remove this line if you dont want the first item to be opened automatically.
$(".faq-question").on("click", function(){
if( $(this).parent().hasClass("active") ){
  $(this).next().slideUp();
  $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
}
else{
  $(".faq-answer").slideUp();
  $(".faq-singular").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $(this).next().slideDown();
}
```